# Java ScriptEngineManager returns null when using custom ScriptEngine

Tags: java, scripting, scriptengine

I previously asked [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277695/how-to-create-methods-at-runtime-for-scripting-purposes) on StackExchange. Because it was put on hold, I'm following the comments and asking about how to fix this instead. To avoid repeating myself and copy pasting an explanation, please read the previous question I asked for the full details.

I'm trying to write my own custom ScriptEngine for Java. I tried extending the `AbstractScriptEngine` and implementing `ScriptEngineFactory` and filling out all the bare minimum required methods just to test if I'd be able to at least start working with scripts. (See the code [HERE](https://github.com/Gamefreak0/SandboxScript/tree/master/src/main/java/me/gamefreak0/ss)) When I ran the following code...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByExtension("sbs"); // <- THIS LINE HERE

    System.out.println(engine);

    try {
        System.out.println(engine.eval("STRING!"));
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The `manager.getEngineByExtension("sbs");` method returns null. I have also tried using `getEngineByMimeType("text/SandboxScript");` as well as `getEngineByName("SandboxScript");` but none of these have worked.

Is there something I set up incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The lookup of custom script engines is via the service provider mechanism (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider), so this must be set up to be able to look up your class by name. In you project's META-INF directory, create folder named 'services' if one does not exist. Within this folder create a file named 'javax.script.ServiceEngineFactory' containing the line of your package/class

```
me.gamefreak0.ss.SandboxServiceEngineFactory
```

Presuming your project and META-INF is set up properly, your ScriptEngine should now be registered and you should be able to look it up by name.

Comment: Is there a way I can do this from inside IntelliJ IDEA's Run Configurations?

Comment: I do not use that IDE so cannot directly guide you, however with Eclipse you can add a META-INF (or other directory) to the build path so that it is accessible through the IDE's debug/runtime environment and deployed with any jar file created. I'd presume IntelliJ IDEA has a similar feature.